# Create one relation from different scopes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a method which get the scope and produce the link to filtered page. This link looks like number of reports

```
def other_total_reports(subjects, action, due_in = nil, locale_clause = nil)
    scopes = []

    scopes << due_in if due_in

    count = scopes.inject(subjects) { |obj, method| obj.public_send(method) }.count
   
    link_to count, { controller: 'user_reports', action: action, filter: filter }, class: ("overdue" if due_in == (:overdue)), target: "_blank"
end
```

updated: the scopes contains only 'where' clauses, so

```
UserReports.unprocessed.videos, UserReports.unprocessed.public_chats, UserReports.unprocessed.answers_only, UserBlockLog.unprocessed.photos, UserReports.unprocessed.questions_only.questions_reasons, UserReports.unprocessed.profiles.profiles_reasons
```

is a chained methods

```
class << self
    def unprocessed
      where state: 'new'
    end

    def profiles
      where origin: ORIGIN_PROFILE
    end

    def questions_only
      where origin: [ORIGIN_QUESTION]
    end
 end
ORIGIN_QUESTION          = 'question'
ORIGIN_PROFILE           = 'profile'
```

.etc

I should count total unprocessed reports but the total number was not quite accurate because of some filters on different relations(scopes), namely:

```
questions_reasons, profile_reasons
```

which is another 'where' clause for items with specific reason, example:

```
reason: '2', origin: 'profile'
```

so when I pass subjects

```
UserReports.unprocessed
```

it didn't works well.
To get the correct number I must combine the specific scopes which was already counted and pass as subjects. Scopes to combine:

```
UserReports.unprocessed.videos, UserReports.unprocessed.public_chats, UserReports.unprocessed.answers_only, UserBlockLog.unprocessed.photos, UserReports.unprocessed.questions_only.questions_reasons, UserReports.unprocessed.profiles.profiles_reasons
```

Later this scope must be used, so it should be an ActiveRecord::Relation which excludes arrays methods. Thank you guys for help!

Comment: Can you clarify? Do your scopes work as expected elsewhere, or is the issue just with this method? If the issue is the scopes, how they defined?

Comment: Do your scopes include something that is not a "where" clause?

Answer (score 0):

Found this way as solution:

```
    total = UserReports.unprocessed.videos, 
            UserReports.unprocessed.public_chats, 
            UserReports.unprocessed.answers_only, 
            UserReports.unprocessed.photos, 
            UserReports.unprocessed.questions_only.questions_reasons, 
            UserReports.unprocessed.profiles.profiles_reasons

    @reports_total = UserReports.where(id: total.map(&:id))
```

Comment: This is going to suffer greatly from a performance standpoint (minimum of 7 queries). Also I am not sure how this works at all given that I assume each scope returns an AR Relation and that relation does not respond to `id`. Additionally, while this may "work", still a bit confused on how, it is very possible that at some point it will just stop working. You are creating an IN clause of Ids based on the results of 6 other queries. Issues here include instantiating N ActiveRecord objects (memory issues) and creating an IN clause from the ID (SQL query length issues).

Comment: These aforementioned issues will just land on your head on day without notice or warning and will likely only impact certain users at first (depending on the number of UserReports) which will make this problem even more difficult to identify immediately, until you think back to this comment at some point in the process of ripping your hair from your head. I would highly recommend you update the post to more clearly define the problem so that we can assist you as necessary in avoiding this avalanche you are creating.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Edited to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

If you scopes have 'where' clauses only, you can use "or" to join your scopes into only one record

```ruby
scopes.each_with_object(subjects).inject(nil) do |memo, (scope, original_record)|
  # Applies the scope to your record
  result = original_record.public_send(scope)
  # You can`t apply your "or" if you don't have any of your scopes applied already
  # So we skip the first iteraction
  next result unless memo

  memo.or(result)
end
```

If your scopes do have more clauses than 'where', you can use [ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#includes_values](https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.1.1/ActiveRecord%2FQueryMethods:includes_values) to include all your scopes "includes" values to use the "include" clause at least

If the other clauses are too complex to join like 'select', 'from', or 'group by', than it would have to adapt each one of them to maybe use an "union" in each scope, and even then, 'group by' clauses for example would not work well, so specify in your question how complex are your scopes if your problem is still not solved